# C++ Illegal Action when Iterating over Vector Buffer

Tags: c++, clang, buffer, chunks, chunking

So I am writing this program to search a binary file for a certain chunk, and I get this error that I don't understand.

Here is the Code to the function, that generates the Error
(also note that the return value is an int, becuase i wanted it to return the size as bytes first, to see if it works)

```
int GetChunkBuffer(ifstream &imageFile, char chunkName[4])
{
    //contains the newly opened image as a whole
    vector<unsigned char> imageBuffer(istreambuf_iterator<char>(imageFile), {});

    //pointer "array" type of thing
    vector<unsigned char>::iterator bufferIterator = imageBuffer.begin();

    for(; bufferIterator != imageBuffer.end(); bufferIterator++)
    {
        if(*bufferIterator == chunkName[0])
        {
            //i think this makes the program faster
            if(*(bufferIterator + 1) == chunkName[1] &&
               *(bufferIterator + 2) == chunkName[2] &&
               *(bufferIterator + 3) == chunkName[3])
            {
                //chunk name matches
                //get length of chunk
                unsigned char len[4] = { *(bufferIterator - 4),
                                         *(bufferIterator - 3),
                                         *(bufferIterator - 2),
                                         *(bufferIterator - 1)
                                        };

                unsigned int chunkLength = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    chunkLength += len[i] << 1;
                }

                return chunkLength;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The File I am opening is a PNG, not sure if that makes any difference.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Which line does the error points out?

Comment: @Rixment no line at all, it just says `Illegal Action`

Comment: Where does `bufferIterator - 4` point to at the first 3 iterations?

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes (which is what you seem to have) as and when they happen, to locate where in your code the crash happened.

Comment: @mch it points at the length of the chunk, as it is specified [here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html). I probably should have clarified that with a comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you have any reccommendation for a debugger and a good tutorial ?

Comment: @youngtrashbag no, for `bufferIterator = imageBuffer.begin();` `bufferIterator - 4` is illegal. If the `if` cannot be true for the first 3 iterations, why don't you skip them?

Comment: @mch you are right, but if the iterator is in the middle of the file, wouldn't it be valid, becuase im doing it in a for loop ?

Comment: Not all paths return (when no matches), leading to UB in those cases.

Comment: `unsigned char len[4]; for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) /**/len[i]` -> Out of bound access when `i == 4`.